# Prove that the ultimate step function is integrable

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider the ultimate step function, $f$ defined on $[0,1]$ as follows: $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=1/n$ for $1/(n+1) < x \le 1/n$ for all $n=1,2,3,\dots$

Prove this function is integrable on the interval $[0,1]$.

I don't quite understand what the function looks like. Is it just a straight line $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$?

Comment: There's trouble with the definition  $f(x)=1/n$ for $1/(n+1)$. Do you mean for $x\in $ some set?

Comment: I am sorry, I miss something after 1/(n+1)...

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: The function is not simply the identity function $g(x)=x,$ although the two functions *do* intersect infinitely often.

Rather, $f(x)=1$ for all $\frac12<x\le1,$ $f(x)=\frac12$ for all $\frac13<x\le\frac12,$ $f(x)=\frac13$ for all $\frac14<x\le\frac13,$ and so on, and $f(0)=0.$ So, we're stepping down as we head from right to left, with the steps getting shorter (horizontally) and closer together (vertically) as we proceed, with $f(x)$ tending toward $0$ as $x$ does.

As for showing integrability, it depends on your definition of "integrable." If it is "bounded, and continuous except on a set of [Lebesgue (outer) measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) $0$," then you're basically done, since $0\le f\le1$ and since $f$ is continuous except at the points $x=\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\frac15,....$ Hence, it is continuous except on a countable set, and countable sets always have Lebesgue (outer) measure $0.$ I leave it to you to prove these facts if you want to use this approach.

Here's another approach that will fit yet another definition of integrability. We define a sequence of functions $u_n(x)$ and $l_n(x)$on $[0,1]$ as follows: $u_1\equiv1,$ $l_1\equiv0,$ and for any positive integer $m,$ we define $$u_{m+1}=\begin{cases}f(x) & \frac1{m+1}<x\le1\\\frac1{m+1} & 0\le x\le\frac1{m+1}\end{cases}$$ and $$l_{m+1}=\begin{cases}f(x) & \frac1{m+1}<x\le1\\0 & 0\le x\le\frac1{m+1}.\end{cases}$$ You should be able to show that $l_n\le f\le u_n$ on $[0,1]$ for all positive integers $n,$ and that for any $\epsilon>0,$ we can find $N$ such that $$0<\int_0^1u_n(x)\,dx-\int_0^1l_n(x)\,dx<\epsilon$$ for all $n\ge N.$ (Each $u_n$ and $l_n$ is a step function, so is integrable.) This shows that $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ by another definition.

If you have a different definition of integrability altogether, let me know.